# Kubernetes Ingress Firewall rules

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

How do you restrict access to a domain when using ingress? I want `www.example.com` to be public but `test.example.com` to be accessible only for a certain IP. I'm guessing I'll have to use iptables on the pods instead? I'm using GKE cluster.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress-web
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
  - host: test.example.com
```

Comment: Have you checked out Firewall Rules? https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#firewall_rules

Comment: Can I block based on Domain name? I can't find a example. I've setup firewall rules before but its always based on IP. In this case, `www.example.com and test.example.com` both share the same IP

Comment: Nope, you can't define rules with FQDN

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ingress, you can configure Cloud Armor on top of it, here you have a guide about how to do it.
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#cloud_armor

This will allow you to block/allow source IPs.